# Code Generation for interface....Quick Actions and Refactorings feature in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

[Click here for demo of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXlmU.gif)
This is happening for Visual Studio Community 2015 
Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3
On Framework 4.7

Here is what the book says (John Sharp, Microsoft Visual Studio, Step by Step, Eight Edition, Page 427.)

"Return to the definition of the TreeEnumerator class.  In the class declaration, hover over the text IEnumerator.  On the drop-down context menu that appears (with a lightbulb icon)--(I assume he means after you right-click)--click Implement Interface Explicitly".

when I right click, I don't see "implement interface explicitly" but I do see "Quick Actions Refactorings", and because another link (which I am trying to find) says this is the right option, I chose it, but nothing really happens.... As if I did nothing...

```
using System;



public class TreeEnumorator<TItem> : IEnumerator<TItem> where TItem : IComparable<TItem>
{
    private TreeEnumorator<TItem> currentData = null;
    private TItem currentItem = default(TItem);
    private Queue<TItem> enumData = null;

    //***** when dealing with a generic class, the constructor does not have <TYPE>
    //NOTICE the name of the constructor is not TreeEnumorator<TItem>
    public TreeEnumorator(Tree<TItem> data)
    {
        this.currentData = data;
    }

    private void populate(Queue<TItem> enumQueue, Tree<TItem> tree)
    {
        if (tree.LeftTree != null)
        {
            populate(enumQueue, tree.LeftTree);
        }

        enumQueue.Enqueu(tree.NodeData);

        if (tree.RightTree != null)
        {
            populate(enumQueue, tree.RightTree);
        }

    }
```

Comment: This works fine for me.  At a minimum, we would need to know the exact version of VS2015 (e.g. Update 1, etc.) to offer suggestions.

Comment: I didn't get it from a link.  I got it from Jhon Sharp's book, Eighth edition of Microsoft C# Step by Step.  Page 427.  I can paste that into the question.  Gimee a minute.  Please vote it back up.   I will fix the question....

Comment: `This website is quick to close your account,` That is not true at all. I am not sure why you thought that.

Comment: Please use LiceCap or similar to show us an animated gif of you right-clicking and selecting `Quick Actions Refactorings` and attached the gif to your question.

Comment: anmated gif added to question

Comment: Change the top of the file to be `using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;`.

Comment: mjwillis.... What you say, makes sense, but I didn't have any red squiggly lines in my code before I added "using System.Collections.Generic" to my code.  Not sure why Visual studio didn't report it as a missing ref.  Anyway, adding the ref did not solve the problem....

Comment: how come extra -1 today?  I made the question much more clearer than yesterday.  I fixed all the issues you guys reported with the question.  Why another point off for doing the right thing, and no points returned for fixing the question?   I have a love-hate relationship with this site.....very helpful, but very annoying.  if I have to keep opening up new accounts, I guess I'll just do that.  The site manager needs to revisit their policies.  Way too strict.

Comment: strange.  i thought upgrading to 2017 would solve.  no cigar...

Comment: some sources hint that this may not work in community edition of software...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code I had created was put in my Solution Items folder.
It was not put in my project folder.
Once I moved it, it works as normal...